# Updating one svn repo from another

Tags: svn

For a project we are about to start, I want a private subversion repo that we will update constantly, and a client-visible one that is only updated when we want the clients to see the changes. That is, we don't want the clients seeing all of our (possibly silly) check-ins to the repo, so we keep all of those to ourselves and sometimes push everything out to the client-visible repo.

Is there a convenient way to bring the client repo into line with the private repo? I don't see such commands in subversion itself, but could be missing them. It isn't hard to write a script that rsync's the private to the client-visible one (excluding syncing the .svn directories), followed by a few svn adds and dels, but that seems clumsy.

Comment: This would be extremely easy with Git. Rebase before you push. With `git svn` you can use Git locally and push to Subversion.

Comment: @tripleee What if there are more than one user who needs access to that _private repo_?

Comment: Use regular access control to manage that. You could have a central Git repo internally if all your developers are comfortable with that, and/or use Git in a completely decentralized fashion.

Comment: @triplee: I am assuming (possibly incorrectly) that you are the one who gave this a -1. I would note that "you're not using the VCS that I prefer" isn't really an indication that the question is not useful. If I was using git for this project, a rebase would be the obvious answer. But the question is specific to subversion for a good reason.

Comment: Why do you think I'm the downvoter? Au contraire, upvoted now to counter, but slightly miffed that you assumed I'd downvote on those grounds.

Comment: Apologies to @triplee, and (seriously) thank you for calling me out on it. If my clients could stomach Git, I'd be there, but the world of VCSs is as full of strong opinions as the worlds of text editors and CMSs.

Comment: At the peril of restating the obvious, with [`git-svn`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html) your master is SVN but you can use Git locally. Your clients won't have to know about Git. I'd think it could satisfy your use case rather nicely, but it's not what you asked about, so I'm staying in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *branches*.

Let's say you setup your Subversion repository like this:

```
* corporate/trunk
* corporate/branches
* corporate/tags
* client/trunk
* client/branches
* client/tags
```

Then, you could use [Path Based Authorization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html) to keep your *corporate branch* invisible to your client. When you want the client to see something, you can merge your *corporate branch* to your *client branch*.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I know about branches, of course: what I didn't know about was that you could limit access to branches in the config file.

Answer (score 1):

Check svnsync, it allow replicate repositories.

Comment: I did look at svnsync, and could not see a way for the second repository to have a punctuated subset of the check points for the first repository. If I missed how to do that, by all means let me know: that would indeed solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Point 1**

> we don't want the clients seeing all of our (possibly silly) check-ins to the repo

contradicts and is not consistent with

> sometimes push everything out to the client-visible repo

**Point 2**

In SVN-world you have to use SVN-lingo in order to be properly understood and not expose themselves as illiterate loser: in SVN we have not "check-ins" (CVS-argo, "commit" in SVN) - and "push" (DVCS-argo, has no commonly accepted and clearly recognizable equivalents in CVCS /SVN as part of CVCS/)

**Draft of solution**

If you want transfer to client-visible repo polished history and only "slices" of development

- Any CVCS is bad choice
- In case of still SVN (and visibility of both repositories from developer's side) you can use trick of "Common UUID+relocate"

  - Client-repo must be created with the same UUID, as developers-repo (have 1 commit into DEV, create CLIENT, dump DEV-repo to dump-file, restore dump into CLIENT with `--force-uuid` option)
  - Work with DEV, as usual
  - On sync-moment, `svn relocate` clean Working Copy (updated to $REVISION_OF_SYNC) of DEV to CLIENT
  - Commit this *modified Working Copy of CLIENT* to CLIENT (all DEV-commits between previous and current sync will be collapsed into single CLIENT-commit)
  - Relocate WC back to DEV
- You can also use tagging for "promoted" revisions and transfer dumps (`svnadmin dump`+`svndumpfilter` or just `svnrdump`) of `/tags/` tree into any CLIENT tree (`svnadmin load` or `svnrdump`)

Comment: Good point on proper lingo; I was indeed lazy with my wording. Agree about any CVCS being a bad choice. I think the Path Based Authorization of branches is probably easier to maintain.